# MongoDB - How much data is too much data?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

I'm building an application that uses MongoDB as a database. I have a lot of products, and I want to log what products a user looks at to the user's database entry. For instance, a user profile looks like this:

```
{
    "email" : "foo@bar.com",
    "name" : "John Snow",
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ecbcc6896652a008000001"),
    "productsViewed" : [
            product1,
            product2,
            product3,
            product4
    ]
}
```

I have two options here. I can log just the `_id` of each product, or I could log entire objects representing the product (name, price, ~100 word description, categories, that sort of thing). The difference in object size is 1 line of text per product vs about 30 lines per product.

I realise that this is probably a trivial amount of data to be concerned about, but if a user has 10,000 `productsViewed` entries, will the ~30x larger difference make any sort of impact? Logging more data is far more useful for my purposes but I'd like to avoid my database calls lagging if the user profile becomes quite large.

**Question is:** At what point (in character length, I guess?) is too much data to store with one MongoDB record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

16 Meg is the limitation for the entire document. This means that all strings etc have to fit within 16 meg. However, before that there are more limitation on your schema which you, yourself hint at:

> but if a user has 10,000 productsViewed entries, will the ~30x larger difference make any sort of impact?

And the answer is yes. First off with the added data of the root user you will probably be over the 16 meg limit, however, further on from this the in-memory `$pull`, `$push` and other sub document operators might have a hard time keeping peformance up. You can sort of mitigate that problem by batching your subdocuments into groups of 100.

However, yet again, you have an even bigger problem: Fragmentation. Since MongoDB stores the record in a single contigeous space on the disk, hence it has settings like padding, you could see considerable fragmentation from odd sized record objects not being reused here.

I would personally say that you should factor off this relation to a separate collection.

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain what you mean by "the entire document"? I'm aware of what databases, collections and records are in relation to `MongoDB` but not sure what 'document' refers to.

Comment: @Jascination in this case a document = record and a record object = an internal respresentation of MongoDBs record